# Rendering a Kable table with images in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, dt, kable

I created an R Markdown HTML report where I am using Kable tables. I am trying to convert this report into a Shiny dashboard, and I noticed that the Kable table from the report does not display the images in Shiny.

This is how the table displays in Rmd:

[image]

This is how the table displays in Shiny:

[image]

This is the code that produces the tables: The images are picked (status_image and significance_image) change depending their `pct_change` and `significant_greater_less_pvalue` values.

```
dt_2 <- cbind(initial_medians_table(), medians_significance_df) %>%
      mutate(notes = "",
             status_image = paste("![](www/", ifelse(pct_change <= 0, "down_arrow_green", "up_arrow_red"), ".png)", sep = ""),
             significance_image = paste("![](www/", ifelse(significant_greater_less_pvalue < input$pvalue_threshold, "significant", "not_significant"), ".png)", sep = ""),
             medians_analysis = paste(medians_analysis, " mins (", round(medians_analysis/(24*60), 2), " days)", sep = ""),
             medians_baseline = paste(medians_baseline, " mins (", round(medians_baseline/(24*60), 2), "days)", sep = "")) %>%
      select(V1, V2, medians_analysis, medians_baseline, change, status_image, significance_image, notes)
```

And this is how I am rendering in Shiny:

ui.R

```
uiOutput("tableset")
```

server.R

```
output$tableset <- renderUI({

    out <- kable(medians_and_significant_test(), align = rep('c', ncol(medians_and_significant_test())), escape = FALSE,
                 col.names = c("High-Level Process",
                                "Deeper-Level Process",
                                "Analysis (Median)",
                                "Baseline (Median)",
                                "% Change",
                                "Performance",
                                "Statistically Significant?",
                                "Notes")) %>%
      kable_styling(c("striped", "condensed", "hover", "responsive"), full_width = F) %>%
      kableExtra::group_rows(index = c("Level 0" = 1, "Level 1" = 3, "Level 2" = 6)) %>%
      footnote(symbol = c(paste("Significance test used:", input$sig_test_selected),
                          paste("p-value threshold used is", input$pvalue_threshold, "to test for significant"))
      )

    HTML(out)

  })
```

I am using the wrong "string" or call for rendering the images in a cell? I am also happy to use DT if anyone knows how to render images from the www app folder on the cell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Would this post help? https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/383#issuecomment-503511391

Comment: The link helped, thanks Phil. The issue was that the string that would call the image was not in the right format:

From markdown syntax:
"![](image_file_name.png)"
Need:
"<img src=image_file_name.png>"

I also dropped the "www/" from the string that reference the folder where the image is.

Comment: Great. You should answer your own question in case someone in the future runs into a similar issue and finds this question.